# Angularjs scope not updating when I select the value from jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, selenium, cucumber

I am writing `cucumber` test with `selenium`. The problem is that there is one dropdown and I select one of the values using jquery, but when I press next it gives error.

Basically angular has not updated it's scope.

```
<select name="837" id="answer_837" class="donothing_to_my_select ng-scope ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="answers[question.question_id]" ng-options="obj.possible_answer_id as obj.answer for obj in question.possible_answers" required="">
    <option class="" value="">--Select Option--</option>
    <option label="b" value="0">b</option>
    <option label="d" value="1">d</option>
    <option label="c" value="2">c</option>
    <option label="a" value="3">a</option>
</select>
```

In the same cucumber, scenario I run this jquery code to select the third option:

```
$('#answer_837 option[label=c]').prop('selected',true)
```

That will select the third option, but, again, it's not updating the angular scope.

I've tried to get the scope object then `$apply`, but it's also not working.

```
 var newVal = $('#answer_837 option[label=c]').val();
 var scope = angular.element($("select")).scope();
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.answers[837] = newVal;
    });
```

Comment: Could you please give the snippet some context by uploading the controller or directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#answer_837').prop('value',2);
$('#answer_837').trigger('change');
```